# How to get pid for cron script?

Tags: shell-script, centos, process

I'm using centOS 7 and  I'm trying to make together these walktroughs:

[Script to check if process is running](https://www.m00nie.com/2011/12/script-to-check-if-a-process-is-running-and-if-not-start-it/)

[Github's example of making sidekiq run as service](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/blob/master/examples/systemd/sidekiq.service)

Nevertheless, both look very smart, I've got stuck when I tried to check the script from the first one manually.

So in /etc/cron.hourly I placed sidekiq_restart with the following script:

```
    #!/bin/bash
# A simple script to check if a process is running and if not will
# restart the process and send a mail.
################################################
# The name of the program we want to check
PROGRAM=sidekiq

# The user we would like notified of the restart
MAILUSER="someone@weeenospam.blah"
################################################

PROCESSPID=$(pidof -s $PROGRAM)
if [ -z "$PROCESSPID" ];
then
# Use systemctl
systemctl stop $PROGRAM.service
systemctl start $PROGRAM.service
# Comment above and uncomment below to use service rather than systemctl
# service $PROGRAM restart
echo mail -s "Service $PROGRAM was found to be stopped on $HOSTNAME at $(date) and has been restarted" $MAILUSER << /dev/null
echo "$PROGRAM had FAILED on $HOSTNAME @ $(date)" >> $PROGRAM-check.log
else
echo "$PROGRAM was running ok on $HOSTNAME @ $(date)" >> $PROGRAM-check.log
fi
exit
```

I ran sidekiq as service with:

```
systemctl start sidekiq
```

And when I check with `ps -aux | grep [s]idekiq`:

```
deploy_+  9883 36.4  0.6 474972 100292 ?       Ssl  14:23   0:02 sidekiq 5.1.3 pnvstart [0 of 20 busy]
```

Looks perfect! But when I try:

```
pidof -s sidekiq
```

It returns just nothing! Of course that means script will be wrong! How to fix that? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm confused - the service file you link to will already restart sidekiq if it crashes (`Restart=on-failure`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your `ps` output, it looks like `sidekiq` changes its own process name to include runtime information: `sidekiq 5.1.3 pnvstart [0 of 20 busy]`. In that case, `pidof` probably doesn't find it because it's looking for exactly "sidekiq".

If you don't plan on starting and stopping sidekiq manually, you can use systemd's own tools: `systemctl is-active sidekiq` will return with error code if sidekiq is not running, and succesfully if it is.

Personally, I'm a friend of exit-soon, so I'd write code along the lines of

```
systemctl is-active sidekiq && exit # all is well

# oh no, it's gone!
systemctl restart sidekiq
mail -s ...
```